# Layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have three buttons in one activity.when each of the button is clicked ,different layout should be shown with in the same activity.for example if first button is clicked,edit boxes and button should be shown.if second buttojn is clicked listview should be shown etc..

Answer (score 0):

- Define different layout files for each layout.
- Then after each click event have the intent call this particular activity recalled.
- Have setContentView() called conditionally ie determining the particular clickevent and vice versa.

This you can do if you want complete activity to be layuot in diffrent manner. Otherwise if you want some widgets to be displayed on button click then it is pretty easy to show them on click event.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna consider a "TabWidget" for this. It actually does what you need. 
[A sample tutorial here.](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-tabhost-tutorial-part-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just include the all the layout elements in your single layout, then use the setVisibility attribute to turn them on and off, depending on which button is pressed.

Something like this pseudo code:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
    view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```